# AngularJs how to filter negative number

Tags: angularjs

In `angularJS` I want to show negative number as red and positive as green.

I would like to apply a conditional `CSS` with `ng-class`. How do I check that number is negative?

```
<span ng-class="{true:'ok',false:'ko'}[number == ?what should I check?]">
    <b>Trend:</b>{{number}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about greater than or equal to 0 (for positive):

```
<span ng-class="{true:'ok',false:'ko'}[number >= 0]">
    <b>Trend:</b>{{number}}
</span>
```

The expression inside `[ ]` will be resolved to the boolean matching the previous statement in `{ }`.

**Note: I'm assuming that the `ok` class is positive (green) and the `ko` class is negative (red).  These css classes should be defined in your stylesheet.*